# Is there a way to conditionally display a command button in a Telerik MVC grid?

Tags: model-view-controller, button, telerik, command

I have a column in my grid reserved for commands as follows:

```
.Columns(c =>
{
   c.Command(cmd =>
                  {
                    cmd.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                    cmd.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                  });
...
}
```

Is there a way to conditionally display the Delete button based on a value of a field in the current row?  I'd like to do something like this:

```
cmd.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image)
         .HtmlAttributes((item.HasChildren == true ? new { style = "display: none"} : null));
```

The problem is that item is not in scope here as it is in a Template column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be best to handle this with the OnRowDataBound client-side event of the Grid. The following JavaScript should work:

```
function onRowDataBound(e) {
    if (e.dataItem.HasChildren) {
        $(e.row).find('t-grid-delete').remove();
    }
}
```

The e variable can be used to access any of your fields (hence HasChildren can be checked if it is true or false) and then all you have to do is look at the specific row ($(e.row)) and find the element representing the Delete button (t-grid-delete).

Comment: that looks like a class selector in which case it should be '.t-grid-delete'

Answer (score 2):

The above answer only works with Ajax binding. If you pass a collection into the Grid during instantiation, then you also have to do something similar in the OnLoad event as well (because the rows aren't actually databound).

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<Borrower>(Model.Borrowers)
    .Name("BorrowersPopupGrid")
    .Columns(cols =>
    {
        cols.Bound(b => b.FirstName);
        cols.Bound(b => b.MiddleName);
        cols.Bound(b => b.LastName);
        cols.Bound(b => b.MailingAddress).Title("Address");
        cols.Bound(b => b.MailingCity).Title("City");
        cols.Bound(b => b.MailingState.StateCode).Title("State").ClientTemplate("<#= MailingState == null ? '' : MailingState.StateCode#>");
        cols.Bound(b => b.MailingZipCode;
        cols.Bound(b => b.TelephoneNumberFirst).Title("Phone 1");
        cols.Bound(b => b.TelephoneNumberSecond).Title("Phone 2");
        cols.Bound(b => b.EmailAddress).Title("Email");
        cols.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit();
                command.Delete();
            });
    })
    .ClientEvents(events =>
    {
        events.OnLoad("BorrowersPopupGridOnLoad");
        events.OnRowDataBound("BorrowersPopupGridOnRowDataBound");
    })
)

function BorrowersPopupGridOnRowDataBound(e) {
    if (e.dataItem.BorrowerId == borrowerOneId || e.dataItem.BorrowerId == borrowerTwoId) {
        $(e.row).find('.t-grid-delete').remove();
    }
} 
function BorrowersPopupGridOnLoad(e) {
    var grid = $('#BorrowersPopupGrid').data('tGrid');
    grid.$rows().each(function(index, row) {
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
        if (dataItem.BorrowerId == borrowerOneId || dataItem.BorrowerId == borrowerTwoId) {
            row.find('.t-grid-delete').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: howcheng - I tried your code in the OnLoad event but grid.dataItem(row) returns undefined.

Comment: In the five months since I originally wrote this, my jQuery has gotten a lot better, so I updated the code example to be more elegant.

empo, I don't know exactly what you're doing, but if you have data in your grid, this really should do the trick. Post your code if you're still having problems.

Comment: I had to switch to Ajax binding for other reasons, but iterating over each row as you've done makes sense to me. Thanks for updating it. Sure it will help someone.